# Create an alias for resource name in Restangular

Tags: angularjs, rest, restful-url, restangular

I have an endpoint `GET /tickets` that return list of tickets. I create a Restangular service to fetch the tickets

```
var Tickets = Restangular.service('tickets');
Tickets.getList().then(...)
```

It works great. I am even using the `Restangular.extendModel('tickets', ...)` method of so every ticket returned gains some special methods.

Now, as my system grows, I have defined a new endpoint that fetches the same tickets, based on some server-side criteria, i.e. `GET /tickets/recently_closed`.

The question is: how to use such endpoint in Restangular so it still thinks that the entities returned from `GET /tickets/recently_closed` are tickets and it enhances them with the same `extendModel` function already defined?

Almost the same example is defined in the [Best Practices for Designing a Pragmatic RESTful API / Aliases for common queries](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#advanced-queries).